# i want to make a button for next and previous song for a playlist

Tags: javascript

ihave a playlist has a button (onclick= runnext())  to run a play list
i want to build a 2 buttons to get the previous song and the next song and keeps the playlist working

```
var i = 1;
function runnext() {
    playingnow = true;
  while ( !player ) {
    var player = document.getElementById("player-" + i); 
    i++ ;
    console.log(i)
    console.log(player)
  
    if(i > 50)
    {
      i=0 ;
      break;

    }
  }
  
  player.play();
  player.addEventListener('ended', runnext);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Where do you store the songs?

Comment: in my sql database

Comment: and when you get it inside your javascript is it an array?

Comment: no it fetch songs by foreach loop as an objects not in array

Comment: Well you should update your question with an example of your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in an array you can do the following.

Create a *pointer* variable which points to the currently displayed element in the array(Your current song).
When the *next* button gets clicked, first check if there is a element at position +1 in the array. If yes display it and increment your *pointer* by 1 to let it point to the next array element.
The same applies to *prev* button just with decrementing instead of incrementing.

```js
const songs = ["song1", "song2", "song3", "song4"];
let pointer = 0;
document.getElementById('out').textContent = songs[pointer]

document.getElementById('nextBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (songs[pointer + 1] !== null && songs[pointer + 1] !== undefined) {
    pointer++;
    document.getElementById('out').textContent = songs[pointer];
  }
})

document.getElementById('prevBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (songs[pointer - 1] !== null && songs[pointer - 1] !== undefined) {
    pointer--;
    document.getElementById('out').textContent = songs[pointer];
  }
})
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
<button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
```